# The Lie bracket of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the matrix commutator

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

**Notation/preliminaries.**

1. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ denote **the Lie algebra** (of left-invariant vector fields) on the Lie group $G$. Its Lie bracket $[.,.]\colon \mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}$ is defined by 
   $$[X,Y]_p(f)=X_p(Y_{\square}(f))-Y_p(X_\square(f))$$
   for any vector fields $X,Y\in C^{\infty}(TG)$, any point $p\in G$ and any smooth function $f\in C^{\infty}(G)$. Here, $X_\square(f)\colon G\to\mathbb{R}$ is the smooth map defined by $q\mapsto X_q(f)$.
2. Let $T_eG$ denote the **tangent space** at the identify element $e$, consisting of all linear maps $C^{\infty}(G)\to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfy the product rule. The tangent space is equipped with the Lie bracket $[\![.,.]\!]\colon T_eG\times T_eG\to T_eG$ given by $[\![X_e,Y_e]\!]=[X,Y]_e$.
3. This gives us a Lie algebra isomorphism $\mathfrak{g}\cong T_eG$. More precisely, one can show that every tangent vector $X_e\in T_eG$ can be extended in a unique way to a left-invariant vector field $X\in \mathfrak{g}$.
4. For the Lie group $G=\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, we can use $x\colon \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ defined by $p\mapsto p$ as global coordinates.
5. We will use $\Big\{\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}\Big)_e\Big\}_{i,j=1}^n$ as a basis for $T_e\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$. Here,  $\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}\Big)_e(f)=\partial_{ij}(f\circ x^{-1})\vert_{x(e)}$ for everh smooth function $f\colon \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$.
6. This gives rise to a vector space isomorphism $T_e\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ via
   $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}\Big)_e\mapsto (a_{ij})$.
7. For any vector field $X$ on $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, we let $M_X$ denote the matrix associated to $X$ via the identifications $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})\cong T_e\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

**Problem.** I want to show that under the identifications $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})\cong T_e\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $[.,.]$ corresponds to the matrix commutator on $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Or more precisely:

> For any vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, it holds that
>   $M_{[X,Y]}=M_XM_Y-M_YM_X$.

**Own attempt.** I have realized that it suffices to show that for two tangent vectors $X_e=\sum_{i,j} a_{ij} \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}\Big)_e$ and $Y_e=\sum_{i,j} b_{ij} \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}\Big)_e$, it holds that
$$[X,Y]_e=\sum_{i,j,k} \big(a_{ik}b_{kj}-b_{ik}a_{kj}\big)\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}\Big)_e.$$

The first step, I guess, is to find the extensions $X$ and $Y$ of $X_e$ and $Y_e$, respectively. I'm more or less convinced that for any $p=(p_{ij})\in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, it holds that
$$X_p=\sum_{i,j,k} p_{ik}a_{kj}\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}\Big)_p.$$ Can we conclude from this that
$X=\sum_{i,j,k} x_{ik}(\square)a_{kj}\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}\Big)_\square$
holds?

I've then tried to compute $[X,Y]_e(f)$ for an arbtirary $f\in C^\infty(\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}))$, using the formula in (1) above, and end up with the scary expression
$$[X,Y]_e(f)=\Bigg(\sum_{i,j} a_{ij} \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}\Big)_e\Bigg)\Bigg(\Big(\sum_{i,j,k} x_{ik}(\square)b_{kj}\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}\Big)_\square\Big)(f)\Bigg)-\Bigg(\sum_{i,j} b_{ij} \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}\Big)_e\Bigg)\Bigg(\Big(\sum_{i,j,k} x_{ik}(\square)a_{kj}\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{ij}}\Big)_\square\Big)(f)\Bigg)\,,$$
from which I have no idea where to go. Am I at all on the right track here? It feels like my main problem is that I get a little bit lost in all the notation and all identifications we make back and forth. Indeed, proofs of this fact can be found in many text books (e.g. Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* p. 194), but the notation there tends to be too coarse for me to follow what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "scary expression" will give you what you want, but you need to be careful with the names of the indices, you have some conflicts there, like $i$ appearing twice in not summed expressions.

Instead, let's streamline things a bit, for $A,B\in \mathfrak g$ we have $$ A=a^{ij}\partial_{ij}|_e,\ B=b^{ij}\partial_{ij}|_e $$ with the components being constants, and summing over repeated indices are understood. A generic group element is denoted as $x^{ij}$ and $\partial_{ij}$ are the holonomic frame vectors associated with the canonical coordinate system mapping group elements to their matrix elements.

We also recall that given any manifold $M$ with local chart $(U,\varphi)$ (with $\varphi(x)=(x^1(x),...,x^n(x))$), if two vector fields $X=X^i\partial_i$ and $Y=Y^i\partial_i$ are given, then their commutator is locally given by $$ [X,Y]=\left(X^j\partial_j Y^i-Y^j\partial_j X^i\right)\partial_i. $$

**Left multiplication:**

Let $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow G$ be a smooth curve such that $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\dot\gamma(0)=X=X^{ij}\partial_{ij}|_x$. Let $g=(g^{ij})\in G$ be a group element. Then $$ (l_g)_\ast X=\frac{d}{dt}g\gamma(t)|_{t=0}=^!gX=g^{ik}X^{kj}\partial_{ij}|_{gx}, $$ where at the equality sign with the exclamation mark we use the fact that the group elements are just ordinary matrices embedded into $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

So left translation of vectors in $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ is just ordinary left multiplication of the vector (which is a matrix, rememeber!).

**The derivation:**

By the previous, the left invariant vector fields corresponding to $A,B\in\mathfrak g$ (also denoted the same way) are given by $$ A_x=x^{ik}a^{kj}\partial_{ij}|_x\ B_x=x^{ik}b^{kj}\partial_{ij}|_x. $$

If we now reinterpret the $x^{ij}$ from being specific variables to being *coordinate functions*, we can also write the vector fields without evaluation at a specific point as $$ A=x^{ik}a^{kj}\partial_{ij}\ B=x^{ik}b^{kj}\partial_{ij}. $$ the commutator is then $$ [A,B]=(A^{mn}\partial_{mn}B^{ij}-B^{mn}\partial_{mn}A^{ij})\partial_{ij}, $$ where $$ A^{ij}=x^{ik}a^{kj}, $$ and similarly for $B$. This is $$ [A,B]=\left( x^{mr}a^{rn}\partial_{mn}(x^{ik}b^{kj})-x^{mr}b^{rn}\partial_{mn}(x^{ik}a^{kj}) \right)\partial_{ij}=^!\left(x^{mr}a^{rn}\delta^i_m\delta^k_n b^{kj}-x^{mr}b^{rn}\delta^i_m\delta^k_n a^{kj}\right)\partial_{ij} \\ =\left( x^{ir}a^{rk}b^{kj}-x^{ir}b^{rk}a^{kj} \right)\partial_{ij}. $$ At the equality with the exclamation mark we have used that $\partial_{mn}x^{ij}=\delta^i_m\delta^j_n$ and that the coefficients $a^{ij},b^{ij}$ are constants.

For the identity element we have $x^{ij}(e)=\delta^{ij}$, so $$ [A,B]_e=\left(a^{ik}b^{kj}-b^{ik}a^{kj}\right)\partial_{ij}|_e=[A_e,B_e], $$ where the last expression is the ordinary matrix commutator of the matrices $A_e,B_e$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm bit confused by the equality $[X,Y]=(X^j\partial_jY^i-Y^j\partial_jX^i)\partial_i$ though. I'm able to obtain $[X,Y]=X^j\partial_j(Y^i\partial_i)-Y^i\partial_i(X^j\partial_j)$, but I can't seem to get any further.

Comment: Or wait, is this just the product rule? If I'm not mistaken, we get $$[X,Y]=X^j\partial_j (Y^i)\partial_i+\color{blue}{X^jY^i\partial_j\partial_i}-Y^i\partial_i (X^j)\partial_j-\color{blue}{Y^iX^j\partial_i\partial_j}$$ when we expand my expression. But for smooth functions $f\in C^{\infty}(U)$, it holds that $\partial_i\partial_jf=\partial_j\partial_if$. So the terms in blue cancel out, and we end up with $$[X,Y]=X^j\partial_j (Y^i)\partial_i-Y^i\partial_i (X^j)\partial_j=X^j\partial_j (Y^i)\partial_i-Y^j\partial_j (X^i)\partial_i\,,$$ 
which is equal to your expression. Correct?

Comment: @OskarHenriksson Yes, basically.